# Call a bean AFTER successful spring security login?

Tags: spring, spring-security

If I have spring security working, how can I have it call a bean to initialize all my user data once it has logged in? I can do a Servlet Filter but it calls that on every request. I want to just call some init code to load some user data into the session after the user logs in.

Answer (score 1):

When the user logs in correctly spring security call an instance of `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`. What you want to do is create your own bean and use that to perform whatever extra actions you want.

Your class would probably look something like this:

```
public class YourAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

       @Override
       public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

         //do whatever you want
         super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
     }
}
```

Also register your class as a spring bean

```
<beans:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler"
            class="your.package.YourAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
```

and add it to the form login security configuration as the value of `authentication-success-handler-ref`

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a great solution and I have it working in one condition, if I include the <beans:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler"
            class="your.package.YourAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/> in my spring-security.xml. If I include it in myapp-servlet.xml it can't find it (can't resolve bean reference)?! Any ideas why? Shouldn't it be able to?

Comment: @user3594045 Glad to help! It all depends on what you configuration looks like. It's not a given that you can add bean in any configuration and it will work.

Comment: Interesting. I did not know that. I thought Spring loaded all it's dependent configurations first and THEN started all the wiring. This is working then! Thanks!